# need sql to represent relation negation and date compare problem

Tags: select, dbms

I have the following tables:

- Employee(eid,ename,salary,did,classification)
- Project(pid,pname,did,budget,ddate)
- Department(did,dname,floor,head)
- dbudget(did,byear,budget)
- Project(pid,pname,did,budget,ddate)
- Onproject(pid,eid,fdate)

did department identifier, so we need something that is in employee.did but non on project.did

and I want to retrieve all of the projects whose duedate is not passed, and that all of its workers belong to a department  that is not responsible for the project.

now, I don't know how to check if the ddate is over(ddate is due date, and I don't know if it's passed or not), and how to represent it in a query.

I'll show the query I constructed so far:

```
SELECT   Project.pname 
from         Project 
FULL OUTER JOIN Employee 
on   Project.did <>  Employee.did 
AND ....
```

(don't know how to check if ddate is passed) is there a function to show date in SQL to compare (so the difference will be positive) or any trick to work with the given info?

Comment: postgresql, but if possible, need some general sql because i later have to translate it into relation calculus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not simple as it involves 2 entities/tables (`Employee` and `Project`) that have 2 relationships between them. One is through the `Department` (a project belongs to a department, an employee belongs to a department) and the other through `Onproject` (which shows that an employee has started working on a project).

Moreover, the answer needs a relational division query (*"all is workers belong ..."*). There are many ways to do relational division - and all are in the range of not simple to very complicated.

One way to express the problem is with a (double) negative. Instead of finding projects where all workers do not do something, find projects where none of the workers do something. This can be expressed with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Project AS p
WHERE p.ddate > CURRENT_DATE 
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM Employee AS e
            JOIN Onproject AS w
            ON w.eid = e.eid
        WHERE w.pid = p.pid
          AND e.did = p.did
      ) ;
```

Or with `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Project AS p
    JOIN
      ( SELECT p.pid, p.did
        FROM Project AS p
        EXCEPT
        SELECT w.pid, e.did
        FROM Employee AS e
            JOIN Onproject AS w
            ON w.eid = e.eid
      ) AS pw
      ON pw.pid = p.pid
WHERE p.ddate > CURRENT_DATE ;
```

Given the tables definitions, the latter can be (simplified?) to use `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Project
    NATURAL JOIN
      ( SELECT pid, did FROM Project 
        EXCEPT
        SELECT pid, did FROM Employee NATURAL JOIN Onproject
      ) AS pw
WHERE ddate > CURRENT_DATE ;
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. i was wondering, since i need to turn it later into a relation algebra expression, is there anyway to bypass CURRENT_DATE? or do you know if CURRENT_DATE can be used in relation algebra? thank you very much again for your effort!

Comment: Perhaps you ask your teacher/tutor about that. I don't see why you can't use it. The same you would translate a `WHERE year = 2000` condition to relational algebra. CURRENT_DATE is a (run time) constant. Not much different than a constant.